# Javascript array extension method gets iterated in for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration, prototype-programming

I have created a JavaScript extension for an array object as follows:

```
Array.prototype.where = function (lamda) {
var results = [];

for (var i in this) {
    if (lamda(this[i])) {
           results.push(this[i]);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

When I iterate through the array using a for loop like:

```
var myArray = [1,2,3,4];

for(var i in myArray){
   alert(myArray[i]);
}
```

...my extensions are enumerated as well.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This behavior is by design.
`for` / `in` loops iterate over every property in an object, including those inherited from prototypes.

You can check `if (myArray.hasOwnProperty(i))` to skip inherited properties.

However, you should use a regular `for` loop instead.
Javascript's `for` / `in` loop is not intended to loop over arrays.

Comment: Thanks for your response. i'm still new to javascript and am used to using the enhanced for loops like in C#. I've changed my javascript to use a regular for loop and all is well. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

That's javascript's normal functionality. the `for .. in` loop gets all of an object's keys because it is meant for looping over an object, not an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a non-enumerable property to Array, you can do it like this:

```
Object.defineProperty( Array.prototype, "where", {
    value: function where( i: number, j: number ): void {
        ...
    }
} );
```

see here: [Change Array.prototype in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39579042/change-array-prototype-in-node-js)